# What is the best way to parallel two shunt resistors using a switch?

Tags: current-measurement, shunt, voltage

What kind of switch in place of SW1 will have minimum amount of error in current readings?

Max current is 10 A and we should be able to control the switch digitally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIxinU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This looks like bad design. Most mechanical switches are going to have a  contact resistance of 100 m\$ \Omega \$ and any electronic solution will also create a voltage drop. You're only gaining a sensitivity factor of 2 so it's probably not worth doing.

Comment: @Transistor It isn't practical at all? anyway to compensate for the errors?

Comment: And what about a digitaly controlled mosfet with a low Rdson (<10mOhm)?

Comment: I've been looking at this circuit for quite a bit now, and I still can't make out why you would want to do this, so it's very hard (for me at least) to really recommend something you should do. So, why do you want to add a second shunt resistor in parallel?

Comment: @MarcusMüller This way I can have a higher voltage drop at low currents so the voltage drop can be readable by OP07 with uV input offset error, yes I know there are better op amps and dedicated ICs, they're either expensive or not available for me...

Comment: @ElectronSurf generally, this is a measurement problem: I'd recommend not trying to improve the accuracy through adding more inaccurate resistors to the problem, but by improving the linearity and gain, and noise, of your amplifier stage! Only once you're actually mathematically limited by thermal noise·necessary bandwidth should you try with larger resistors than 50 mΩ... You're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller First I should be able to read the low voltage and then I can add gain to it, still the same problem. I need an op amp like [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa189.pdf) which I don't have access to 

Comment: how small are your currents? DC or AC (if AC, which frequency)? Not convinced the OP07 is the real problem here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 1mA DC and 50uV voltage drop over 0.05 ohm resistor. I found this [op amp OP177**G**](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP177.pdf), it seems better than OP07 a bit more expensive but still affordable, what do you think?

Comment: that does indeed look a bit better, but 50 µV is something that an *instrumentation amplifier* built from three OP07 should be able to amplify! [Book on implementation of instrumentation amplifiers and their use](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/designers-guide-instrument-amps-complete.pdf). You can buy instrumentation amplifiers "in a package", but you can also build them from discrete opamps.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry to interrupt you; The differential amplifier is on the low side of the circuit, do you think I can get away with OP07 if I add a diode to the ground line to increase the op amp inputs minimum voltage above ~0.6V?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to assess that; adding a diode brings a nonlinearity in all this which might be benign, or not. I'd *really* use PSPICE or LTSPICE or ngspice with a good op07 model to simulate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guys here pointed out, this may be not the best design idea. First of all, your shunts are of the same value, you will only get twice smaller resistance (there must be a reason, but 10x would kinda make more sense? Depends on your project of course).

You could use a mosfet or even two MOSFETS in parallel (to halve the Rdson) to open a path to the second shunt. Relays have some contact resistance which is greater than that.

Just a random idea that visited my mind: why not to make a current mirror with larger shunt? Of course more components introduce error, there is some small vdrop on the BJT then (bjt current mirrors are more accurate tho in terms of reproducing current). Actually, you can mirror current into two or three circuits with different shunts or just one. Of course, this may and will add to component cost.

If you use current mirror and use some 100R or 10k shunt there or whatever, you can actually use MOSFET to change shunt value because MOSFET's resistance will already be negligible comparing to shunt.

Anyway, this is a random flow of mind, but maybe I'll give you some fresh way to look at your problem.

Comment: I actually had a similar problem, but I have 10R and 1k shunts and I don't even care to disconnect 1k when I connect 10R, because it's so negligible (1% error for my application is nothing). And I use relay because I apply analog voltage there, I must be able to send some 0.05V, so I went for a relay that will disconnect and connect on hardware level (reed relay is quiet)

Answer (score 2):

The lowest on-resistance switch is likely to be a MOSFET. Various manufacturers make them, and some have on-resistances as low as 1mΩ.

This will introduce some error in the measurement.  A 1mΩ on resistance would increase the resistance of the combo from 50.0mΩ to 50.5mΩ.

I would agree with the comment by Transistor though. While this should work, there is probably a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do with this design.